# Angular.js service return $http success data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

In my app, I want to create a service that looks in the backend to check if a user is logged in and returns the user data and privileges. My factory service looks like this:

```
app.factory 'Session', ['$http', ($http) ->
  getSession: ->
    $http.get("/admin/session")
]
```

Right now, I handle success and errors for the service in my controller shown below.

```
$scope.session = Session.getSession()
  .success((data) ->
    # Set the logged in user
    $scope.admin = data

    # Limit any privileges         
  )
  .error((data) ->
    # Logged in user not found so rediret to login screen
    window.location = "/user/login"
  )
```

My problem is that I need to repeat that same code in a lot of different controllers. Is there a better way to handle this? I am thinking I might need to do something with $rootScope but I do not understand how that works.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking...

Comment: I want to know if there is a more efficient way of accomplishing this so I don't have to repeat all of this code in every controller. Basically, I want the controller to be able to get the logged in user from the service. If it fails, I want the service to tell the page to redirect to the login screen. I don't want to have to handle the success and error of the promise in every controller.

Comment: Could you just handle the error in your service instead?

Comment: When I do that, I can't return the successful data from the Session $http.get to the controller. So far, the only way I have come up with is returning the whole promise.

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried? It should be able to just chain the `.error()` in your service.

Comment: Do you want to repeat the `$http.get("/admin/session")` for each individual controller? Shouldn't you run this only once?

Comment: Running it once could be beneficial, though running it multiple times would keep communicating with my server to see if the session is still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the logic inside service itself. You will have to use promises for returning success data  to the controller. So for controller, it will be something like this:

```
   Session.getSession().then(function(data){
      $scope.admin = data;
   });
```

And you will handle your errors in service. Note that this is pseudo code.

```
app.factory 'Session', ['$http', ($http) ->
  getSession: ->
    return $http.get("/admin/session")
           .success(data){}
           .error(){ //... redirect user}
]
```

Comment: There is no need to create another promise using `$q.defer()`, you could just chain the error callback and return the original promise.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? return $http.get().success(//handle success logic).error(// handle error);

Comment: Yes, that what I mean.